# RequestContext.Principal.Identity.Name is empty in web api 2 post

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I'm new to web api and I seem to be having an issue with getting the name of the signed in user inside of my post method. Im using

```
RequestContext.Principal.Identity.Name
```

However, this only seems to be returning an empty string. It works fine in my get method, but not in the post. Here's my entire method

```
[Route("receive")]
        [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage Receive(PostmarkInboundMessage message)
        {
            if (message != null)
            {
                // To access message data
                var headers = message.Headers ?? new List<Header>();

                // To access Attachments
                if (message.Attachments != null)
                {
                    var attachments = message.Attachments;

                    var c = new CVService();
                    var user = string.IsNullOrEmpty(RequestContext.Principal.Identity.Name) ? "unknown" : RequestContext.Principal.Identity.Name;

                    c.UpdateLog(user);

                    foreach (var attachment in attachments)
                    {
                        // Access normal members, etc
                        var attachmentName = attachment.Name;

                        // To access file data and save to c:\temp\
                        //if (Convert.ToInt32(attachment.ContentLength) > 0)
                        //{
                        //    byte[] filebytes = Convert.FromBase64String(attachment.Content);
                        //    var fs = new FileStream(attachmentSaveFolder + attachment.Name,
                        //                                   FileMode.CreateNew,
                        //                                   FileAccess.Write,
                        //                                   FileShare.None);
                        //    fs.Write(filebytes, 0, filebytes.Length);
                        //    fs.Close();
                        //}
                    }
                }

                // If we succesfully received a hook, let the call know
                return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Created);    // 201 Created
            }
            else
            {
                // If our message was null, we throw an exception
                throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError) { Content = new StringContent("Error parsing Inbound Message.") });
            }
        }
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you **send the header (token)** in both methods GET and POST and also, set the *[Authorize]* filter in both methods or the controller itself so you will be rejected if the token is not being send